# How to setup LanguageTool in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, languagetool

May I ask how can I configure/setup LanguageTool in Eclipse? I don't know how to start my project since I don't know how to setup LT properly.

Comment: Maybe you can read this : https://www.eclipse.org/babel/downloads.php  See "Installing the language packs".

Comment: Clone the [LanguageTool  Git repository](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool) and in the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the cloned repository and choose _Import Projects..._. This will detect and configure the Maven projects automatically.

Comment: @Chen-Hai These are language packs for the Eclipse IDE. The question was asked about the Java library [_LanguageTool_](https://languagetool.org/), which is a spell and grammar checker.

Comment: @howlger where can I find that Git Repositories? I already downloaded the Github Desktop but I can't find it there.

Comment: @ayraley Just drop the [link of the GitHub project website](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool) onto you Eclipse Java IDE and a Git clone dialog will pop-up (no additional software is required for that).